# Why won't my program inject my .dll properly?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll, unicode

Been stuck for a few hours making a (simple) dll injector that takes a .dll file and a process as arguments and then injects said .dll into the process, and I'm about to start tearing my hair out.

It doesn't function properly, and for no obvious reason either. The dll simply won't load into the process, but without any error messages being displayed. I did the exact same thing but with ANSI functions instead of Unicode and it worked like a charm, which after some testing is leading me to believe it's PROBABLY a problem with the file path not being loaded properly but I have no idea why.

I've attached my entire source code below and added some comments to hopefully clarify somewhat. And like I said, if I'm right, then the important part should start somewhere around:
//Get the full path of our dll and store it in a variable

Help a bro out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HANDLE hSnapshot, hProc = NULL;
    PROCESSENTRY32 PE32;
    PE32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    WCHAR injProcName[100] = {NULL}, injDllName[100] = {NULL};

    //Let user input options
    cout << "Dll injector started!" << endl << "Please enter the name of the dll you would like to inject: ";
    wcin >> injDllName;
    cout << "Enter the name of the target process: ";
    wcin >> injProcName;

    //Create snapshot
    hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);
    Process32First(hSnapshot, &PE32);

    //Load the first process into PE32 and loop to see if target process is running
    do {
        if(wcscmp(PE32.szExeFile, injProcName) == 0) {
            wcout << PE32.szExeFile << " found!" << endl;
            wcout << "Attempting to open " << injProcName << ".." << endl;
            hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, PE32.th32ProcessID);
                if(!hProc)
                {
                    cout << "Failed to open process!" << endl;
                    return 1;
                }
            break;
        }
    }
while(Process32Next(hSnapshot, &PE32));

    if(!hProc) {
        cout << "Unable to locate process!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    cout << "Process successfully opened!" << endl;

    //Get the full path of our dll and store it in a variable
    WCHAR DllPath[MAX_PATH] = {NULL};
    GetFullPathName(injDllName, MAX_PATH, DllPath, NULL);
    wcout << DllPath << endl;

    //Allocate memory in target process
    cout << "Allocating memory.." << endl;

    LPVOID DllMemAddr = VirtualAllocEx(hProc,
        NULL,
        wcslen(DllPath),
        MEM_COMMIT|MEM_RESERVE,
        PAGE_READWRITE);

    //Write our path into target process memory
    wcout << "Writing dll to target process.." << endl;
    WriteProcessMemory(hProc,
        DllMemAddr,
        DllPath,
        wcslen(DllPath),
        NULL);

    //Get the memory address of LoadLibraryW
    LPVOID LoadAddr = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryW");

    //Finally, start a new thread with the address of LoadLibraryW and our dll path as argument
    cout << "Executing dll in remote process.." << endl;
    CreateRemoteThread(hProc,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)LoadAddr,
        DllMemAddr,
        NULL,
        NULL);
    cout << "Dll sucessfully injected!" << endl;
    cin.get();

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wcslen` returns length in `wchar_t` units. But `VirtualAllocEx` and `WriteProcessMemory` receive a length in `byte` units. So you only write half the string, because `wchar_t` is two bytes wide. And you did not write the null terminator.

You need to pass `(wcslen(DllPath)+1)*sizeof(wchar_t)`.

---

Incidentally, your ANSI code was probably broken too because, presumably, it also missed the null terminator. But you probably got away with it by chance.

A little error checking would not go amis, while we are in the business of looking at your code. And initialising `DllPath` is a little pointless when you follow it with the call to `GetFullPathName`.

Comment: Yep, this was the problem, thank you so much mate.
I didn't have to add one byte to the returned value from wcslen for some reason though, just multiply it by two.

Comment: No, you need to add the one on, just as per my answer. Otherwise you won't write the null terminator.